# Web pages displays differently depending on URL

Tags: asp.net, url

If I access a certain page, say MyPage.aspx, on my ASP.NET site by using the URL ABC.XYZ.COM/mypage.aspx it displays a grid within a tab (Ajax control toolkit) normally.  If I access that same page with the URL ABC/mypage.aspx (which works because our network is setup to add .XYZ.COM) the grid in the tab displays completely different. No server-side redirection is occurring other than load balancing between two servers. I've verified same exact code is deployed to both servers in the environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you examined the mark-up/css/js using the browser? I would delve into firebug for a while and inspect everything before I proceeded!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IE, check the security zone.  The URL with just the server name is probably in the "Local Intranet" security zone, but the fully qualified domain name is probably in the "Internet Zone".  Different security zones have different settings.

There's an option that forces all "Local Intranet" sites to be displayed using compatibility mode.  That has cause me problems in the past.

Comment: Would the same apply to Firefox? I'm not familiar with Firefox.